# Shutdown hangs on Ubuntu 17.10 on Lenovo ThinkPad E370 "mmc0: Unknown controller version"

Tags: shutdown, lenovo, 17.10

In the log file -

```
mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems
```

and a few more error messages. Shutdown hangs for eternity.

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 022554 
[ IBUS ] sd 2:0:0:0: 
[sda] No Caching mode page found     
wpa_supplicant[1143]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none 
wpa_supplicant[1143]: dbus: Failed to construct signal 
wpa_supplicant[1143]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp5s0 flags: No such device
```

And then multiple:

```
INFO: task kworker/u8:0:5 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a fix / workaround?

The earlier version (17.04) does not have this problem.

Comment: Could you please provide the logs you saw, as well as a more detailed explanation of the problem?

Comment: The problem mainly manifests in hanged shutdowns.
Additional log entries:

nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 022554 [ IBUS ]
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found

Comment: wpa_supplicant[1143]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
wpa_supplicant[1143]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
wpa_supplicant[1143]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp5s0 flags: No such device

And then multiple:

INFO: task kworker/u8:0:5 blocked for more than 120 seconds.

Comment: Shutdown hangs on `Ubuntu 17.10` on `Lenovo Ideapad 110` too

Answer (score 0):

This is kernel 4.13.0 issue, fixed in 4.13.5. I had to download compile and install it manually from kernel.org. After that shutdown works fine.

P.S. Thinkpad e570